# Reading in files as objects instead of variables in python

Tags: python, oop, object, variables

After recently starting a role which essentially incorporates professional software development in python, I have noticed in the code that I am working with that people are tending to read in files as objects instead of variables, and I cannot understand why.

For example, I work with a limited amount of raster files. In the parts of the code that deal with these raster files, there might a class defined explicitly for reading in the rasters. The class takes a file location as in input and will then utilise the python package `rasterio` to open, read and access other characteristics of the file, but then stores these as attributes. For further example, we may have something like the following:

```
class test(object):
    def __init__(self, fileLocation):
        self.fileRead = open(fileLocation)
        self.fileSplit = self.fileRead.split()
```

My instinct would have been to just read the file straight in as a variable and access its properties when I needed them, avoiding the expenditure of extra effort.

I know the idea of classes is to allow for streamlined data handling when dealing with quantities of similar types of data (i.e. student information for students in a school), but this class might initiate one instance in each run of the parent program. So to me, it seems to be a bit overkill to go to the effort of creating a class just to hold the information obtained through `rasterio`, when it would probably be much cleaner just to access the file data as you want it through explicit calls with `rasterio`.

Now, this sort of way of structuring code appears to be quite prevalent, and I just can't seem to understand why this would be a good way of doing things. As such, I wondered if there is some hidden benefit that I am missing which someone could explain to me? Or else to disregard it, and carry on in the manner outlined.

Comment: " but then stores these as attributes" while a regular file object will give you a 1-shot iterator. It's not possible to say from your question what this is useful for, but I think the purpose should be evident enough in the code base vs. Having an object that you iterate once and it's spent

Comment: Ask the authors, simple as that. There isn't always a right or wrong answer, sometimes it's just different. Speak to the authors of the code you're seeing, ask them why they're writing in the way you think could be improved, and suggest to them ideas they may have overlooked - or spotted and mitigated.